# RxPparazzo retrieves the same images when I select more than one image

Tags: android, rx-java, rxpaparazzo

I coose [RxPparazzo](https://github.com/FuckBoilerplate/RxPaparazzo) to manage the images in my app, but I'm still having the same problem. I don't know why when I select more than one image from gallery, the lib retrieves always the same image per image that it should have been added.

```
/**
 * Pick some images from gallery using RxPaparazzo lib.
 */
private void takePhotosFromGallery() {
    RxPaparazzo.takeImages(this)
            .usingGallery()
            .subscribe(response -> {
                if (response.resultCode() != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    response.targetUI().showUserCanceled();
                    return;
                }
                response.targetUI().loadImages(response.data());
            });
}
```

[image: Same image]

[image: Video]

**UPDATED**

Fixed in version [0.1.3](https://github.com/FuckBoilerplate/RxPaparazzo/releases/tag/0.1.3)

*The lib duplicate images* ?

[image: duplicate images]

**UPDATED**

Here the explanation why RxPaparazzo create new images.

[remove images after retrieving them](https://github.com/FuckBoilerplate/RxPaparazzo/issues/6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for use [RxPaparazzo](https://github.com/FuckBoilerplate/RxPaparazzo)

I've just released a [new library version](https://github.com/FuckBoilerplate/RxPaparazzo/releases/tag/0.1.3) which hopefully fixes this issue.

I say 'hopefully' because I haven't been able to reproduce the bug, but looking at the file names, which matches, I think they were saved at the same second, so I've added the milliseconds to the end of the filename.

Try it out and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: it's work! Thank you!. I have another issue. When I choose images from gallery, the lib create new images. I mean, duplicate the images in the gallery. Do you prefer I report this at github or should I create other answer here?

Comment: Hi!, I've answered you [on github](https://github.com/FuckBoilerplate/RxPaparazzo/issues/20)